# CPAN installs fail on EC2 / Linux AMI: "Couldn't untar"

Tags: perl, amazon-ec2, cpan

I am on an EC2 Linux AMI instance attempting to use CPAN to install various CPAN modules. Starting with a typical install (YAML is just one example)...

```
sudo yum install perl-CPAN
Package perl-CPAN-1.9402-127.15.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]> install YAML
```

... and while CPAN downloads and attempts to install the module and dependencies, I repeatedly get the following:

```
Using Tar:/bin/tar xvf "YAML-0.84.tar":
Couldn't untar YAML-0.84.tar
```

I checked and tar and /bin/tar are installed and working properly.

Any info would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you configure CPAN? Try "o conf" in the cpan shell. Does /bin/tar actually exist on your system?

Comment: I did set it up (editing the orig. post) and this is the entry for tar after cpan> o conf: "tar [/bin/tar]". I was able to install some modules too, not sure how these did not require tar. tar is on the system in /bin/tar and works.

Comment: you probably need a more modern version of tar -- try installing Archive::Tar

Comment: This did it the trick. Even better, cpan> install Archive::Tar did not result in "Couldn't untar" :) Thanks, @so-not-liopa.

Comment: @sonotliopa you should re-post your comment as an answer so it can be marked.

Comment: Are either of you able to do this? I do not yet have enough stackoverflow karma to answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem when I was running on a 512M VM.  Increasing the allocation to 1G fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the version of tar on the EC2 box is too old to untar the YAML distribution.

The simplest solution is to install `Archive::Tar` so in the future the CPAN shell can use that rather than the command line `tar` on the machine.  This can be done by typing

```
cpan> install Archive::Tar
```

Fortunately the CPAN shell is able to install Archive::Tar without running into the same problems.

(as per @so-not-liopa comment above, adding as an answer so this is no longer listed as a question without answers)

Comment: Couldn't untar Archive-Tar-2.00.tar when i do: "cpan> install Archive::Tar" :(